# Least-squares solution to a transformation between coordinate frames

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, numerical-linear-algebra, least-squares

Suppose I have four coordinate frames in 3D space: `A`, `B`, `X` and `Y`. `A` and `B` are fixed. `X` and `Y` can move, but there is a fixed transformation between `X` and `Y`. This transformation is denoted `T_XY`, and it is this 4-by-4 transformation matrix (homogeneous coordinates) that I want to determine.

Now, I can take a series of measurements. At each measurement step, I can record the value of `T_AX`, and `T_YB`. So, I can measure the transformation between `A` and `X`, and the transformation between `Y` and `B`. I can then take as many measurements of these two as I want (the measurements have noise), and create a least-squares solution. Other than `T_AX` and `T_YB`, all other transformations are unknown.

So, in summary, I have the following transformations:

```
T_XY : fixed and unknown (this is what I want to determine)
T_AB : fixed and unknown
T_AX : variable and measurable
T_YB : variable and measurable
```

Is this possible? Is this a linear or a non-linear problem? If `T_AB` was known, then perhaps I could gather a series of equations in the form:

```
T_YB * T_XY * T_AX = T_AB
```

and solve this as linear least-squares. However, `T_AB` is unknown, which to me suggests this is a non-linear problem...

Below is a diagram visualising these coordinate frames and transformations.

Thanks!

[image: Coordinate frames and transformations]

Comment: I'm afraid that there is no reasonable way how to obtain $T_{AB}=T_{YB}T_{XY}T_{AX}$ if $T_{XY}$ is more or less arbitrary.